# Google Places API AutoComplete City only after selecting

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I am using Google Places API for an auto complete feature and its working really well, so when I start typing, it display a list of cities, states, country. Which is what I am expecting, however when I select a location, I want just the city name in the input field. Not the states and country, just the city. Is this possible?

```
function initialize() {
        var input = document.getElementById('City');
        new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((input), { types: ['geocode'] });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


<input id="City" placeholder="" class="required form-control" name="City" required="" type="text" />
```

Also is it possible to exclude countries and states? I am really looking for a list of cities, for example if I type in Canada, Canada appears, The input text is for cities only. We do not care about the states or countries.

Comment: You are going to have to do it all programmatically to do this, so you're making your life a lot harder by overriding the given functionality.  I guess you have to ask yourself, is there a good reason why you want to do this?

Comment: I was able to get only cities to appear by changing my type geocode to cities. But when I select a city, the city, province or state and country appears in the input text box. I only want the city in the input text box. How would I do about that? I can't take the value and split it into an array by spaces because some city names have multiple spaces in its name.

Comment: I guess I could use the comma to split the string into an array, but do city names have commas in them?